References output coming in alphabetical order but not as per my cite
I am using overleaf .
In bibtex file
@inproceedings{1,
  title={Hybrid software and system development in practice: waterfall, scrum, and beyond},
  author={Kuhrmann, Matthias and Münch, Jürgen and Diebold, Philipp and Linssen, Oliver},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the International Conference on Software and System Processes},
  pages={31--40},
  year={2019},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{2,
  title={Scaling agile methods to regulated environments: An industry case study},
  author={Fitzgerald, Brian and Stol, Klaas-Jan and O'Sullivan, Rory and O'Brien, Dermot},
  journal={Journal of Systems and Software},
  volume={155},
  pages={25--37},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

References not showing in the order I cite .   The first citation \cite{1}  is coming as 16th in references list !!! coz its all in alphabetical order in References

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{your_bib_file_name}


Citation ordering is determined by your BibTeX style, not the order in your .bib file - can you show an example containing \bibliographystyle?

If you want the citations in the same order as in the .bib file do \nocite{*} at the beginning of the document. But with many citations, this is the worst method for making the bibliography clear to the reader.

If you want to preserve the order in the .bib file (but I don't know why), use \nocite{*}.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{1,
  title={Hybrid software and system development in practice: waterfall, scrum, and beyond},
  author={Kuhrmann, Matthias and Münch, Jürgen and Diebold, Philipp and Linssen, Oliver},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the International Conference on Software and System Processes},
  pages={31--40},
  year={2019},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{2,
  title={Scaling agile methods to regulated environments: An industry case study},
  author={Fitzgerald, Brian and Stol, Klaas-Jan and O'Sullivan, Rory and O'Brien, Dermot},
  journal={Journal of Systems and Software},
  volume={155},
  pages={25--37},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{3,
  title={Title},
  author={A. Uthor},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2024,
  pages={1-3},
}

@article{4,
  title={Title},
  author={U. Athor},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2024,
  pages={1-3},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

Here we cite in random order \cite{3}, \cite{2}, \cite{4}, \cite{1}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}

I used filecontents* just to make the example self-contained.

If you omit \nocite{*}, you get citation order.

Do a favor to your readers and use alphabetical sorting.
